# cant access my site is my ip blocked by ISP

Tags: ip, website, blocking, isp

I want to know if my ISP has blocked my website www.indolog.com . If i use another ISP it works fine.
Below are the tracert log

```
C:\>tracert www.indolog.com

Tracing route to indolog.com [199.223.208.216]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     3 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     4 ms     2 ms     1 ms  ras.beamtele.net [183.83.192.1]
  3     1 ms     3 ms     1 ms  ras.beamtele.net [183.82.14.5]
  4     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  115.113.205.29.static-hyderabad.vsnl.net.in [115
.113.205.29]
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8   137 ms     *      137 ms  if-2-2.tcore2.WYN-Marseille.as6453.net [80.231.2
17.2]
  9   146 ms   133 ms   133 ms  if-9-2.tcore2.L78-London.as6453.net [80.231.200.
14]
 10   137 ms   133 ms   134 ms  if-2-2.tcore1.L78-London.as6453.net [80.231.131.
2]
 11   132 ms   133 ms   132 ms  80.231.130.130
 12   136 ms     *      141 ms  Vlan900.icore1.LDN-London.as6453.net [80.231.60.
6]
 13   135 ms   132 ms   133 ms  ge-2-1-0.mpr1.lhr2.uk.above.net [195.66.224.76]

 14   132 ms   163 ms   133 ms  ge-6-0-0.mpr1.lhr2.uk.above.net [64.125.24.221]

 15   212 ms   212 ms   211 ms  so-0-1-0.mpr1.dca2.us.above.net [64.125.27.57]
 16   208 ms   210 ms   208 ms  xe-0-3-0.cr1.dca2.us.above.net [64.125.29.17]
 17   266 ms   278 ms   269 ms  xe-0-2-0.cr1.iah1.us.above.net [64.125.25.114]
 18   243 ms   243 ms   241 ms  xe-2-0-0.cr1.lax112.us.above.net [64.125.25.45]

 19   241 ms   241 ms   241 ms  xe-0-0-0.cr2.lax112.us.above.net [64.125.30.234]

 20   243 ms   245 ms   245 ms  xe-3-1-0.er4.lax112.us.above.net [64.125.21.194]

 21   242 ms   242 ms   241 ms  64.125.195.218.t00833-03.above.net [64.125.195.2
18]
 22   253 ms   253 ms   260 ms  sc-smv1424.servint.net [206.214.212.28]
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

But if i use a different internet connection using other ISP it opens perfectly well. Below is the other tracert log. Please help me ..

```
C:\>tracert www.indolog.com

Tracing route to indolog.com [199.223.208.216]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    84 ms    87 ms    85 ms  220.224.141.129
  2    94 ms    90 ms   103 ms  115.255.239.89
  3    91 ms    74 ms   108 ms  124.124.251.245
  4   109 ms    94 ms    92 ms  62.216.147.101
  5   439 ms   217 ms   234 ms  so-0-1-0.0.pjr02.ldn001.flagtel.com [85.95.25.13
7]
  6   256 ms   262 ms   235 ms  so-1-0-0.0.cjr02.ldn004.flagtel.com [85.95.25.10
]
  7   211 ms   231 ms   237 ms  ge-2-1-0.mpr1.lhr2.uk.above.net [195.66.224.76]

  8   231 ms   212 ms   230 ms  ge-TBA.mpr1.lhr2.uk.above.net.24.125.64.in-addr.
arpa [64.125.24.221]
  9   337 ms   307 ms   306 ms  so-0-1-0.mpr1.dca2.us.above.net [64.125.27.57]
 10   301 ms   317 ms   301 ms  xe-0-3-0.cr1.dca2.us.above.net [64.125.29.17]
 11   313 ms   345 ms   333 ms  xe-0-2-0.cr1.iah1.us.above.net [64.125.25.114]
```

Let me know if its blocked by my ISP or any other issues.

Thanks,
Manzoor

Comment: That website looks like it was made 5 years ago and hasn't updated sense... What's it for?

Comment: Also it doesn't look like you're reaching the nameservers, if other IPs let you access it it's *probably* your IP.

Comment: Did you make any DNS changes recently?

Comment: Your **ISP**, not your **IPs** sorry.

Comment: Sounds like the website is blocking your ISP not the other way around.  Of course I can't figure which tracert is for which ISP ( the working one or the not working one 0.